# Failed to connect with RabbitMQ server when sending large amount of messages

Tags: node.js, express, rabbitmq

I am using Cloudamqp to connect with RabbitMq when I am trying to send 10 messages its publishing data successfully to the queue but when I am trying to send 2,000 messages its showing connection failed error shown below:

```
Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 15.206.75.114:5671
 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
 errno: -111,
 code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 syscall: 'connect',
 address: '15.206.75.114',
 port: 5671
}
Error Error: Expected ConnectionOpenOk; got <ConnectionClose channel:0>
 at /home/digvijay/test/test-lorien/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:167:14
 at /home/digvijay/test/test-lorien/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:159:12
 at TLSSocket.recv (/home/digvijay/test/test- 
lorien/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:507:12)
```

I am reading the Excel file using XLSX library and sending those rows to the queue. Below is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const XLSX = require("xlsx");
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3300;

// Reading our test file
const file = XLSX.readFile('./limit9.xlsx')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

 const sheets = file.SheetNames;
 for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    const temp = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(
        file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[i]])
    temp.forEach((res) => {
       
            sendData(res); //Here sending data to the queue
       
    });
   }
});


function sendData(res) {

   amqp.connect(`amqps://nuogafvveJoldl_RhEyfs7qJzX0BIRep6J8rFIN-0@puffin.rmq2.cloudamqp.com/xxxxxxx`, (err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error",err);
    }
    else {
        connection.createChannel((err, channel) => {

            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            else {
                let queu = "review_data";
                channel.assertQueue(queu, {
                    durable: false
                });
                var json = JSON.stringify(res);
               channel.sendToQueue(queu, Buffer.from(json));
            }
         });
       }
    });
 }
```

Why is it throwing connection error when I am sending large amount of messages but works fine for sending few messages?